# typeahead with bootstrap and codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, typeahead, twitter-bootstrap-2

i saw a lot of ways to make typeahead, but still can't working with mine. did i make a mistake?
here is my code.

view : personal.php

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $('#search').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query) {
     $.ajax({
      url: "messages/search_name",
      type: "post",
      data: "search=" + query,
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
       typeahead.process(data);
      }
     });
    }
   });
  });
</script>

<input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="typeahead">
```

controller : messages

```
public function search_name() 
        {
              $data = $this->mysms_model->search_name_person();

              echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

model : mysms_model

```
public function search_name_person() 
    {
          $office = $this->input->post('search');

          $this->db->select('name');
          $this->db->from('contacts');
          $this->db->like('name', $office);
          $query = $this->db->get();

          $office_array = array();
          foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
           $office_array[] = $row->name;
          }
          $data['office'] = $office_array;

          return $data;
    }
```

my table name is contacts(cid, name).
thank for helping me.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap? Using Bootstrap v2's Typeahead, or Twitter's Typeahead.js?

Comment: im using Bootstrap v2's Typeahead, and my version of bootstrap is v2.3.1.